# Rotate Grid around cursor position?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8

I have this function:

```
private void RightTap_Rotate(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = (CompositeTransform)N.RenderTransform;
        obj.Rotation += 90;

    }
```

So, after right-click to Grid (N) it's rotate to 90, but not around cursor position (around the left corner, yeah).

What I need to use for rotate it around cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the center point for the transformation:

```
private void RightTap_Rotate(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = (CompositeTransform)N.RenderTransform;
    Point cursorPos = Mouse.GetPosition(yourControl);
    obj.CenterX = cursorPos.X;
    obj.CenterY = cursorPos.Y;
    obj.Rotation += 90;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I should using for «Mouse»? I tried «Control.Mouse» and «System.Windows.Inout» but nothing happened.
VS 2013, Windows 8.1

Comment: Use [`e.GetPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.righttappedroutedeventargs.getposition) to get the position.